what particle shall I use when I thank someone from behind them? like when I say たあんじろ [ ] ありがとう what particle shall I use? or won't I even use one?
I just wanted to thank tanjiro (but not infront of him like I am saying "thanks to tanjiro" infront of other people) for cooking with me in my art piece, so I wanted to know which particle shall I use (が or に )

Not that it matters much, but assuming it was meant to be like the Demon Slayer character name, it would be spelled たんじろう.

oh yeah, ur right I forgot about it sorryyy

When addressing someone, you generally don't need any particle after their name. You can simply say "たんじろう、ありがとう" regardless of whether the person is in front of you. Similarly, you don't need any particle when you add someone's name before or after saying こんにちは, ごめんなさい, さようなら, はい, etc.
Notes:

You may still need an honorific name suffix such as さん, 様 or 先生, depending on who you're addressing. If you're talking to an anime character, a name suffix is usually not necessary, but some otaku prefer to use 様 to show their respect to the character.
Using に and saying "たんじろうにありがとう" (≈ "(Say) thanks to Tanjiro") is not incorrect, but this sounds like you're making a speech that everyone should thank him. If you're directly and personally saying "thanks" to him, don't use に.
Actually, Japanese has two vocative particles, よ and や. While grammatically correct, using them will make you sound pompous, like a prophet or an elderly person.


thank you so much!! now I understand!

I would say that thanking someone is inherently something you do directly, but I think I understand your meaning.
In English, if I say "thank you, Tanjiro", the mental model is very direct: "thank" is an action, I am doing it (I am the grammatical subject), and Tanjiro is the one who gets thanked (the direct object), whom I'm thanking for some unspecified thing (an indirect object).
But Japanese handles this social situation completely differently. ありがとう is a sound shift from [有]{あ}り[難]{がた}い, an i-adjective literally meaning "difficult to exist". That is: you are talking about what Tanjiro did that makes you thankful. If I say たんじろさん、ありがとう then my use of たんじろさん is really vocative; I'm using it to get Tanjiro's attention. Tanjiro doesn't actually play a role in the claim I'm making.
So if you need to be indirect, then the fact that "Tanjiro did this" is another description of the thing that Tanjiro did. You need a nominalizer such as の to turn a nested sentence like "Tanjiro did this" into a reference to "the thing that Tanjiro did". Then this can be marked with が or は normally, with the usual nuance.
So I suppose theoretically, you could say something like たんじろさんが〇〇をしてくれたのがありがとう. But I don't know if it's natural. I would probably say something more like たんじろさんは〇〇をしてくれて、すごく助かった "Tanjiro did 〇〇 (for me), and it was very helpful".
But if you really want to focus on the good will of others, rather than their actions, I think you had better address them directly.
If you mean that you want to give credit to Tanjiro for playing a role in the art piece, there are specific conventions for that sort of thing, and I think you should ask about it more precisely.

thank you that was so helpful!!
